# what is the difference between "return num1<num2" and "return num2-num1" in comparator

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator

I am learning how to write the comparator in C++. At first time, I return `num1<num2`, as a result I get a set in ascending order. Then I return `num1>num2` and I get a set in descending order. Now I try to return `num1-num2` which should equal to `num1>num2` in my opinion, I get a set in descending order as predicted. But when I try to return `num2-num1`, I still get a set in descending order. How could it happen? Is there any difference between `return num2-num1` and `return num1<num2`?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    using namespace std;
    
    struct myCmp{
        bool operator()(const int& num1, const int& num2){
            return num2-num1;
        }
    };

int main()
{   
   set<int,myCmp> st;
   st.insert(1);
   st.insert(2);
   st.insert(3);
   for(auto it=st.begin();it!=st.end();it++){
       cout<<*it<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should `num1-num2` be equivalent to `num1>num2`?  One returns an `int`, the other returns a `bool`.

Comment: Your comparator is borked (i.e. it doesn't provide *strict weak ordering*) and as far as C++ is concenrned, anything can happen.

Comment: Hint: the only value that is false when you do `num2 - num1` is when the result is `0`.

Comment: `return num2-num1;` is only false when num2 and num1 are equal.  They are true if one is larger than the other so `return num2-num1;` is equivalent to ``return num1>num2 || num1<num2;``

Comment: @JerryJeremiah "*so `return num2-num1;` is equivalent to `return num1>num2 || num1<num2;`*" - or simply `return num2 != num1;`

Comment: Thank u everyone, I realize my mistakes now. I thought “a non-positive expression equals to false” for granted. An expression equals to false only when it is 0. I think I need to review the most basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I try to return `num1-num2` which should equal to `num1>num2` in my opinion

That is incorrect.

> Is there any difference between `return num2-num1` and `return num1<num2`?

Yes.

`num2-num1` returns an integer value that is the result of subtracting the value of `num1` from the value of `num2`.  Since your comparator returns a `bool`, a result of `0` will be converted to `false`, and *any other result* will be converted to `true`.

`num1<num2` returns a boolean value specifying whether or not `num1` is actually less-than `num2`.  Any value of `num1` that is less-than the value of `num2` will return `true`, all other values will return `false`.

So, as you can see, both approaches return completely different things.

[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has the following *requirement*:

> `std::set` is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type `Key`. **Sorting is done using the key comparison function `Compare`.** Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.
>
> Everywhere the standard library uses the [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, **two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other**: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

Using `return num1<num2` (or `return num1>num2`) satisfies that requirement, but `return num2-num1` breaks it.

For example, let's assume `a = 1` and `b = 2`.

Using `num1<num2`, you get the following:

```
  !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)
= !comp(1, 2) && !comp(2, 1)
= !(1 < 2) && !(2 < 1)
= !true && !false
= false && true
= one is less-than the other, so not equal, which is correct!
```

Using `num1>num2`, you get the following:

```
  !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)
= !comp(1, 2) && !comp(2, 1)
= !(1 > 2) && !(2 > 1)
= !false && !true
= true && false
= one is less-than the other, so not equal, which is correct!
```

Using `num2-num1`, you get the following:

```
  !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)
= !comp(1, 2) && !comp(2, 1)
= !(2 - 1) && !(1 - 2)
= !(1) && !(-1)
= !true && !true
= false && false
= neither is less-than the other, so equal, which is incorrect!
```

Comment: Thank u a lot, I thought for granted that a negative expression equals to false. Now I know where the problem is. This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow, I was really moved to see so many people answering my questions for me. Thank u guys!

Answer (score 2):

> I try to return `num1-num2` which should equal to `num1>num2` in my opinion

Let's try that:

```
num1 = 5;
num2 = 10;

num1>num2 // false
num1-num2 // -5, true
```

So, no, your assumption is incorrect. All results when `num1 != num2` are converted to `true` in a boolean context, and only when `num1 == num2` will the result be converted to `false`.